# Scroll to Top When Use set interval In ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**I get some result using ajax.Now i want to scroll to top.Now scroll top is not working because I use setInterval. When I scroll to top then automatic scroll Down.How to fix it**

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 300px;height: 400px;margin: auto;border: 1px solid;overflow-y: scroll;" id="result"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function data()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "data.php",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                    $('#result').scrollTop($('#result')[0].scrollHeight);
                }
            })
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            data();
        },1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Data.php**

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$res = '';
while($i <= 50)
{
    $res .= "<h2>Hello World !!</h2>";
    $i++;
}
echo $res;
?>
```

Comment: I think there is not any data in `$('#result')[0].scrollHeight`. can you put some dummy value like 50 aside that and check

Comment: it's not working

Comment: use just `$('#result').scrollTop()` and it should work fine as scrolltop method does not accept any arguments.

Comment: @RohitMittal it does: [scrollTop( value )](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop2)

Comment: @empiric check official doc of jQuery https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: @RohitMittal and what did I link you in my comment: https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop2 -> `.scrollTop( value )`?

Comment: haha thanks @empiric for correcting me right. Appreciate it!!

Comment: @RohitMittal no worries ;-)

Comment: If i use scrollTop outside Ajax then Its not working because my content is load from ajax.